# Xcode: export snapshots to another Mac

Tags: xcode

I want to export  my Xcode project and   its snapshots  from iMac to  MacBook.

Together with snapshots  do I also have to  export derived data and archives?
Xcode version is 5.0.2
Thank you.
Valery

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried using snapshots already? There is a button in the organizer that exports your snapshots to a designated location.[image]

Comment: And if I do so  will the snapshots  be workable   without   exporting  derived data that probably is related to  these snapshots?

Comment: Derived data is where your build outputs, indexes and logs are. They aren't necessary when exporting snapshots. Basically, snapshots are duplicates of your project's workspace, files and project settings. Derived data has nothing to do with it :)

Comment: Oh, I see.Then it should be easy.
Thanks a lot!